# CSS deactivate a hover of a parent class

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, parent-child, parent

I have two style sheets in page.html:
parent.css and child.css

In parent.css I have:

```
#MAINTable tr:hover
{ 
    background:#C0C0C0;  
}
```

I need to deactivate this from child.css

I'm doing:

```
#MAINTable tr:hover{text-decoration: none !important;}
```

But this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

PD: Sorry if the question was too simple, learning CSS here

Comment: since the rules are different, what exactly do you need to deactivate?

Comment: tex-decoration and background has nothing to do with each other mate...

Comment: learning css here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to overwrite the background:

```
#MAINTable tr:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent.css defines the background, but child.css only sets the text decoration. They both stay, due to the nature of CSS. You need to override it manually.

In child.css:

```
#MAINTable tr:hover{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background: none transparent !important;
}
```

If child.css is after parent.css you don't need the second `!important`. I used `none transparent` so that it also overrides any background images.